# How to hook drupal commerce line item create

Tags: drupal, drupal-commerce

I want to process something when a new commerce line item create, is there any hook can do this?

Or is there another methods can do this?

Thanks at first!

Answer (score 0):

you can use a rule. (admin/config/workflow/rules)

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your reply, here is some related topic: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/134691/how-to-hook-drupal-commerce-line-item-create